# How to fix Firefox rotation glitch?

Tags: css, firefox, rotation

I'm afraid I'm facing a render glitch in the current Firefox (24.0), while Chrome (30) renders the same code as expected.

Here's the code: http://dabblet.com/gist/6982745

HTML:

```
<div class="triangle"></div>
```

CSS:

```
.triangle {
    height: 50%;
    width: 40%;

    position: relative;
    top: 50px;
    left: 50px;

    background-color: black;
    overflow: hidden;
    /*
     * Here comes the malicious line:
     */
    transform: rotate(-18deg);
}
.triangle:before {
    content: "";
    width: 200%;
    height: 300%;
    position: absolute;

    background-color: white;

    transform-origin: left top;
    transform: rotate(-52deg);
}
.triangle:after {
    content: "";
    width: 200%;
    height: 300%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 38%;

    background-color: white;

    transform-origin: left top;
    transform: rotate(26deg);
}
```

Basically, there's a black square (.triangle) which is partially covered by rotated white squares (:before and :after) to create a triangle. The black square itself is rotated by 18 degrees - which causes Firefox to render some kind of gray border around .triangle - even if the both white squares should cover every pixel in this area.
Chrome, as a reference, omits such a border.
A little experimenting showed me that the glitch only occurs with rotations other than 0°, 90°, 180° ...

My questions are: Am I doing something wrong? (I know that there are simpler ways to create a triangle - it's just a simplified example) Is there a known workaround for this glitch? I already tried box-shadow and border - both without success.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19353043/text-not-in-same-position-after-rotating

Comment: You should post the code most likely causing your issue directly on SO instead of linking to external resources. Just as everything required to answer a question should be in the answer, the same must be true for questions.